# Is there a formula to convert from Thomas Bros Map page & grid to a latitude/longitude?

Tags: geolocation, gis, geocoding

I'm working on a project that contains Thomas Brothers Map page and grid numbers.  Is there a way to programatically convert from this map page to a latitude & longitude?

An Example would be for the intersection of the US101 & I405 freeways.

ThomasBrothers: 561-3G   (page-grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but I don't have a lot of experience with Thomas bros maps.  Are you talking about printed version of the maps or is there a link somewhere to an online map?

If you just need a few lat/longs, then you can look up the locations that correspond to the grid and get the lats and longs manually at many websites, including http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

If you provide a link to a Thomas bros map that you are using, I might be able to help further.

By looking at the link above, you can determine that US 101 and I-405 has a latitude of  34.16073390017978 and a longitude of -118.46952438354492.

Answer (score 1):

Your best source would be the map publisher. If they choose to help, someone there can tell you exactly what you need to know. If they won't help you, it's unlikely that they've released the information to anyone else.

If that's the case, you could do some work by hand to correlate one point from the map grid to your target coordinate system. Effectively, you could reverse engineer a mapping ["datum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_datum#Datum) for each page. You'd also have to know what map projection was used to render the maps, so that you can calculate the transform from the map coordinates to the geographic coordinates as you move away from your "origin". Finally, you'll need to establish the orientation of the map, since different notions of "north" exist.

It sounds like the Thomas maps use a new grid for every page, rather than bleeding the grid continuously from page to page. If that's the case, you'll have to correlate one point on each map. For example, find a spot where a map grid intersection coincides with a notable road intersection. Then you can find the coordinates of the road intersection using a map with latitude and longitude (a topographic map, [TerraServer](http://terraserver-usa.com/), etc.). Doing this with two points on the same vertical grid line should help you establish the north used on the map as well.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that each of the nine regions has a grid derived from a Lambert conformal conic projection with custom parameters, so you cannot write a conversion program without the parameters.

Comment: best not to leave your email address in plain text here

Answer (score 0):

I've also got ThomasBros. pages that I would like to convert to lat/long for lookup against Google Maps API. They also provided something called TBXY ... not sure what this is -- perhaps some notation for GPS/lat/long?

```
<Area>"El Cajon"</Area>
<ThomasBrothers>"1297 5E"</ThomasBrothers>
<TBXY>"6481390:1827008"</TBXY>
```

Comment: I'd be guessing TBXY is Thomas Brothers X Y.  It probably is probably a northing and easting pair in some projected coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Brothers Maps invested a lot when developing their GIS system to create their digital mapping system.  Though the first "digitally produced" map was Sacramento County-1990, the development began back in 1986.  I expect that their map projection equations are a well guarded trade-secret, which Rand McNally now owns.  I'd don't know those equations, but would also like to know them.

There are 9 projections covering the 48 states.  If you know the equations for Los Angeles, it is valid across California & Nevada.  Oregon & Washington have their own projection.  Arizona, New Mexico, Colorado, and Utah share another projection.

I do know this...

As many know, the page grid is an exact 1/2 mile square, or 2640 feet by 2640 feet.  The coordinate measurement unit is 1 foot.

To determine the Thomas Brothers XY Coordinate, get one or more of the Thomas Guide CD- ROM maps, which were recently discontinued.  The last ones produced for certain California counties were the 2008 edition.  Last editions for Seattle, Portland, Las Vegas, and Phoenix/Tucson were the 2007 edition.  Each is still available on the Rand McNally website for $20.

When you geo-code a group of addresses, you'll see an output file with the TGXY coordinates and Lat/Lon for the addresses you specified, and the page # and grid that point is in.  Once that file is open, you can click on the map to add additional geo-coded points, which will also provide both the coordinates.  The output file is saved in an Access database ".mdb" file.

If you know a lot about map projections or solid geometry, the set of corresponding TGXY and Lat/Lon coordiantes will provide you some good data for testing.

As you mentioned San Diego Page 1297, I'll provide its bordering coordinates.
West x=3062760
East x=3086520
North y=0985040
South-y=0966560

This is not in range of the "TBXY" you found on Google.  Maybe it's the same projection, with a relocated origin.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that a simple relationship exists between GPS and TG pages, given that some regions share numbering systems and some do not (Los Angeles + Orange Counties share, Riverside + San Bernardino Counties share but not with LA/OC, and so on).

Since no one has an answer, I decided tht I wanted one, so I made one.

Here's the trick: locate the very top-left of grid A1 of the first page in your particular county. Get the GPS for that point (I used Google Maps). Then calculate any two ponts on the same latitude line (it's helpful to find two streets on the same inner grid line), then two on the same longitude line. GPS both pairs, and calculate the distance (only the latitude distance for one pair, and only the longitude distance for the other pair). You will find that they are not the same (not a perfect square).

I got:
0.03° latitude = 2.5 miles, or 0.01 miles per grid ↕
0.03° longitude = 2.0 miles, or 0.01 miles per grid ↔
(correct, they are not the same, and both values are heavily rounded)

Now, from there, knowing each page is 9 x 7 grids {^[A-HJ][1-7]$}, do:
page = (top-left/starting page) + ( 30 * int( y `/ 7 ) ) + int( x` / 9 )
because pages stack on top of each other vertically in LA/OC, my test bed, by jumps of 30)
grid = 'A' + int( x `% 9 ), 1 + ( int( y` ) % 7 )

I'm still tweaking the mathl it's accurate about 70% of the time right now. I'll post the math when I get it perfected.

Sadly, Rand McNally bought out and CLOSED Thomas Brothers maps (replacing them with their own product), but some states require first responders to still carry the Guides by law (including California), so you can still find a few editions ... for DOUBLE the price from the old days. If you can find an old Digital Edition online (circa 2004~2007), AND the serials to install them, AND a virtual machine to run them on Windows Xp or earlier (they malfunction on Vista, and were discontinued shortly thereafter), you can see the numbers yourself.